# How to external js method in Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Hi I have a jQuery defined method named "Mymethod()" in widjets.js which needs to be called in AngularJs Controller written in Typescript.

Comment: What's your exact question? Consider posting some source code as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a jQuery defined method named "Mymethod()" in widjets.js which needs to be called in AngularJs Controller written in Typescript.

The jQuery method will most likely need access to the DOM element. Therefore instead of doing this in a controller you should wrap in an angular directive.

Docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive